# Demystify global class operator design pattern

Tags: ruby, architecture

I was working through a online code bootcamp tutorial on "advanced class methods" when I noticed something strange. First the **Person** class is defined, and specifically, the **#normalize_names** method. Basically, this method iterates through every instance of class **Person** stored in **@@all**, and capitalizes the first and last names stored in **person.name**

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name
  @@all = []
    def self.all
     @@all
    end

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @@all << self
  end

  def self.normalize_names
    self.all.each do |person|
      person.name = person.name.split(" ").collect{|w| w.capitalize}.join(" ")
    end
  end
end
```

Then the tutorial explains that "Given how complex normalizing a person's name is, we should actually encapsulate [the method] into the **Person** instance." So, subsequently the **#normalize_names** method is refactored to look like this.

```
def normalize_name
    self.name.split(" ").collect{|w| w.capitalize}.join(" ")
end

def self.normalize_names
    self.all.each do |person|
      person.name = person.normalize_name
    end
end
```

Thus "The class method that acts on the global data of all people is simplified and delegates the actual normalization to the original instances. This is a common pattern for global class operators." Why is this common? What about the complexity of normalizing names merits this design pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glaring thing that the first `normalize_names` implementation is missing, is a way to update just a single person? one option is to write another class method, which accepts a single person instance. In the interest of separation of concerns, this could be split into two methods:

```
def self.normalize_names
  # note that 'self' can be omitted in most cases
  all.each { |person| normalize_name person }
end

def self.normalize_name(person)
  # note use of proc shorthand to shorten collect { |x| x.capitalize }
  person.name = person.name.split(" ").collect(&:capitalize).join(" ")
end
```

Now at least there is a way to update just a single person (should the need arise). Although there's no firm requirement to use instance vs class methods, it may be desired to have a slightly more terse API, e.g. `person.normalize_name` and not `Person.normalize_name(person)`. That's probably the biggest reason to move it to an instance method, to be honest:

```
def self.normalize_names
  all.each &:normalize_name
end

def normalize_name
  # note that attr_writers ("self.name =") are one of the few places you need 
  # "self", to differentiate it from variable assignment
  self.name = name.split(" ").map(&:capitalize).join " "
end
```